# When the product of two nonholomorphic functions is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let us assume that we have two functions $f(z)$ and $g(z)$, which are not necessarily holomorphic, but whose product $f(z)g(z)$ is holomorphic. Is it always possible to find a function $h(z)$ such that $f(z)=\tilde{f}(z)h(z)$ with $\tilde{f}(z)$ holomorphic and $\tilde{g}(z)=h(z)g(z)$ holomorphic?

**Edit**

Another similar question. Let us suppose that we have two functions $f(w,z)$ and $g(z)$, where $f(w,z)$ is holomorphic in $w$, and $f(w,z)g(z)$ is holomorphic in both $w$ and $z$. Is it always possible to find a function $h(z)$ such that $f(w,z)=\tilde{f}(w,z)h(z)$ with $\tilde{f}(w,z)$ holomorphic in both $w$ and $z$ and $\tilde{g}(z)=h(z)g(z)$ holomorphic?

Answer (score 4):

Well, $h(z)=f(z)$ will always work. And with that solution in hand, actually, we can see that multiplying this $h$ with *any* holomorphic function that has no zeroes (such as $e^z$) will always yield another solution.

Comment: This answers my question! Could I perhaps ask a follow up question? I realized what I really wanted to know was not captured by the original question I asked. I will edit my question to add it.